# Different declarations of the same function/global variable in two files

Tags: c++, c, function, global-variables, forward-declaration

I have 2 questions regarding different declarations of the same function and global variable in two files in case of C and C++ as well.

1. **Different function declarations**

   Consider the following code fragments:

   **file_1.c**

   ```
   void foo(int a);

   int main(void)
   {
       foo('A');
   }
   ```

   **file_2.c**

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   void foo(char a)
   {
       printf("%c", a); //prints 'A' (gcc)
   }
   ```

   As we can see, the prototype differs from the definition located in
   **file_2.c**, however, the function prints expected value.

   If it comes to C++, the above program is invalid due to undefined
   reference to `foo(int)` at link time. It's probably caused by
   presence of other function signatures - in comparison with C, where
   a function name doesn't contain any extra characters indicating the
   type of function arguments.

   But when it comes to C then what? Since the prototypes with the same
   name have the same signature regardless of the number of arguments
   and its types, linker won't issue an error. But which type
   conversions are performed in here? Does it look like this: `'A'` ->
   `int` -> back to `char`? Or maybe this behavior is
   undefined/implementation-defined ?
2. **Different declarations of a global variable**

   We've got two files and two different declarations of the same
   global variable:

   **file_1.c**

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   extern int a;

   int main(void)
   {
       printf("%d", a); //prints 65 (g++ and gcc)
   }
   ```

   **file_2.c**

   ```
   char a = 'A';
   ```

   Both in C and C++ the output is 65.

   Though I'd like to know what both standards say about that kind of
   situation.

   In the C11 standard I've found the following fragment:

   > **J.5.11 Multiple external definitions** *(Annex J.5 Common extensions)*
   >   There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of
   >   an object, with or without the explicit use of the keyword extern; if
   >   the definitions disagree, or more than one is initialized, the
   >   behavior is undefined (6.9.2).

   Notice that it refers to presence of two and more definitions, in
   my code there is only one, so I'm not sure whether this article is a good point of     reference in
   this case...

Comment: You say, "the function prints expected value". But what number did you expect? And why?

Comment: "Does it look like this: 'A' -> int -> back to char?" Note that in C, `'A'` _is_ an `int`. And both examples are undefined behaviour due to disagreeing declarations/definitions.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I meant that it didn't print any random values.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right, I forgot about this. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1. According to C99 specification, section 6.5.2.2.9, it is an undefined behavior in C:

> If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, the behavior is undefined.

The expression "points to" a function taking an `int`, while the function is defined as taking a `char`.

Q2. The case with variables is also undefined behavior, because you are reading or assigning an `int` to/from `char`. Assuming 4-byte integers, this will access three bytes past the memory location where it is valid. You can test this by declaring more variables, like this:

```
char a = 'A';
char b = 'B';
char c = 'C';
char d = 'D';
```

Comment: @undur_gongor You're right, I should have said "accessed" because he's not writing from the other file. I already said "read or write" in the sentence above, but I mentioned only writing in the second sentence.

Comment: It's more clear now. The for declarations should be 4 different variables, no?

Comment: @undur_gongor You're right, in the previous edit (now invisible because it was done within the first five minutes) I had an `int` variable there, but then I realized that the compiler may "pad" `a` with two or three bytes, and decided to switch to `char`s.

Answer (score 2):

That's why you put declarations into headers, so even a C compiler can catch the problem.

1)

The results of this is pretty much random; in your case, the "char" parameter might be passed as an int (like in a register, or even on the stack to keep alignment, or whatever). Or you got lucky due to endianess, which keeps the lowest order byte first.

2)

Likely to be a lucky outcome due to endianess and some added '0' bytes to fill up the segment. Again, don't rely on it.

Comment: In C, `char` and `short` arguments are always promoted to `int`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Could you please give some more details. I don't understand the message.

Comment: @undur_gongor - the answer asserts that "the 'char' parameter **might** be passed as an int...". `char` arguments are always passed as in in C.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I doubt that. When the function `void foo(unsigned char a) { printf("%i\n", (int)a); }` is called with the parameter `321`, the output is `65` (if a correct prototype is visible to the compiler).

Comment: @undur_gongor - doubt it all you like, that's what C does. Note that your example is not calling foo with a char parameter.

Comment: @PeteBecker, IIRC, promotion occurs for functions without prototypes and arguments passed for `...` but that's all what is mandated. Otherwise, you need compatible types and char isn't compatible with int (it even isn't with `unsigned char` and `signed char`).

Comment: @AProgrammer - you're right. I just looked that up, and was about to correct what I said. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Overloaded functions in C++ work because the compiler encodes each unique method and parameter list combination into a unique name for the linker. This encoding process is called mangling,
and the inverse process demangling.

But there is no such thing in C. When the compiler encounters a symbol (either a variable or function name) that is not defined in the current module, it assumes that it is defined in some other module, generates a linker symbol table entry, and leaves it for the linker to handle. In here we have no parameter checking.

And also if there is no type conversion in here. In main, you send a value to foo. Here it's assembly code :

```
movl    $65, (%esp)
call    foo
```

And foo reads it by taking it away from stack. Since it's input value defined as char, It store the input value in `al` register ( one byte ):

```
movb    %al, -4(%ebp)
```

So for given inputs greater than 256, you will see variable `a` in foo, circulates over 256.

About your second question, In C symbols for initialized variables and functions are defined as strong and multiple strong symbbols are not allowed, but I not sure whether is it the case with C++ or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, I've accidentally found the paragraph in C11 standard that covers both issues - it's 6.2.7.2:

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have
>   compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.